# Editor for creating Android layouts in browser

Tags: javascript, android, html, android-layout

I am looking for a widget I can embed in an html page to design Android layouts by dragging and clicking in the browser (much like I would do in Eclipse or Android Studio) rather than editing the XML file manually. So far I can't find anything like that. Does anyone know of a good solution?